# Pandas timerange overlap issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have an issue with pandas dataframes.

Below is my dataframe

```
                ELEMENT                                    TEXT         ID               START                 END  newid
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT03           USECASE1 - ALARM1 -NO OVERLAP  772874243 2021-01-19 18:00:00 2021-01-19 19:00:00      0
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT03          USECASE1 - ALARM2 - NO OVERLAP  772874243 2021-01-19 19:10:00 2021-01-19 20:00:12      1
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT05     USECASE2 - ALARM1 - Fully Contained  772874243 2021-01-19 18:00:00 2021-01-19 23:00:00      1
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT05     USECASE2 - ALARM2 - Fully Contained  772874243 2021-01-19 19:00:00 2021-01-19 20:00:12      1
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT10  USECASE3 - ALARM1 - START-END-RELATION  772874243 2021-01-19 22:00:00 2021-01-19 22:30:00      2
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT10  USECASE3 - ALARM2 - START-END-RELATION  772874243 2021-01-19 22:30:00 2021-01-19 23:00:12      2
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT21                         USECASE3-ALARM1  772874243 2021-01-19 22:00:00 2021-01-19 22:10:00      2
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT21                  USECASE3-ALARM2-NO-END  772874243 2021-01-19 22:15:00                 NaT      3
  OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT4                               USECASE-4  772874243 2021-01-19 17:30:00                 NaT      3
  OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT4                               USECASE-4  772874243 2021-01-19 20:00:00 2021-01-19 23:00:00      3
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT99                               USECASE-5  772874243 2021-01-19 17:30:00 2021-01-19 22:00:00      3
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT99                               USECASE-5  772874243 2021-01-19 20:00:00                 NaT      3
```

The output that I am getting currently is :

```
                ELEMENT               START                 END
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT03 2021-01-19 18:00:00 2021-01-19 19:00:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT03 2021-01-19 19:10:00 2021-01-19 20:00:12
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT05 2021-01-19 18:00:00 2021-01-19 23:00:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT10 2021-01-19 22:00:00 2021-01-19 23:00:12
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT21 2021-01-19 22:00:00 2021-01-19 22:10:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT21 2021-01-19 22:15:00                 NaT
  OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT4 2021-01-19 17:30:00 2021-01-19 23:00:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT99 2021-01-19 17:30:00 2021-01-19 22:00:00
```

It works fine for all the use cases except for Usecases 4 and 5, there is an overlap of time ranges. I need the end time to be "NaT" and not the following:

```
  OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT4 2021-01-19 17:30:00 2021-01-19 23:00:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT99 2021-01-19 17:30:00 2021-01-19 22:00:00
```

Since the time overlaps, i want it to take the Min of the range for the start and the max (in this case NaT). So The expected result is :

```
  OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT4 2021-01-19 17:30:00 NaT
  OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT99 2021-01-19 17:30:00 NaT
```

The final expected end result of all the use cases is:

```
                ELEMENT               START                 END
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT03 2021-01-19 18:00:00 2021-01-19 19:00:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT03 2021-01-19 19:10:00 2021-01-19 20:00:12
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT05 2021-01-19 18:00:00 2021-01-19 23:00:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT10 2021-01-19 22:00:00 2021-01-19 23:00:12
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT21 2021-01-19 22:00:00 2021-01-19 22:10:00
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT21 2021-01-19 22:15:00                 NaT
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT4  2021-01-19 17:30:00                 NaT
 OLT2227-LT3-PON0-ONT99 2021-01-19 17:30:00                 NaT
```

The following is the code that I have used:

```
df['newid']=(df['START']-df['END'].shift()).dt.total_seconds().gt(0).cumsum()
print (df.to_string(index=False))
newdf=df.groupby(['newid','ELEMENT']).agg({'START':'min','END':'max'}).reset_index(level=1)
print (newdf.to_string(index=False))
```

can anyone throw me some light to achieve my goal?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer.
I converted the NaT to a future date and that was a workaround to make the logic work.